# Passing an unknown class as parameter

Tags: c++, oop, templates, casting

I'm a beginner in OOP and i have a hard time with my code. The problem is that i just want to send an unknown class as parameter so that i could do a cast inside the function and call a method from a specific class (that was passed as a parameter) . I want to know if there are some tricks so that i don't have to use templates, because i don't know them very well. My program contains more classes that have methods with the same name, so there won't be problems at this point. If i haven't made myself clear, please leave a comment below and i will do my best to explain. Thanks!

```
void myClass::myFunc( _myInstance, _myMethod,void* object )
{
  ((_myInstace*)object)->_myMethod();   
}
```

Comment: Well, since you've started thinking this way, it might be nigh time to learn templates. They do wonders.

Comment: Is there any way do some little tricks by using "sizeof" or stuff like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in a reasonable way without templates. Maybe you can use some macro in order to achieve a similar effect, but I would highly discourage that as it will probably not give you type safety.

You'll have to use something like this:

```
template<typename Type>
void func(void (Type::*method_name)(), void* object) { 
    (static_cast<Type*>(object)->*method_name)(); 
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
struct A { void fn() { std::cout << "Ok!"; } };

int main() {
    A a;
    void* ptr = &a;
    func(&A::fn, ptr);
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8a46f074929764a)

Comment: In order to use that template for "void func" i have to type "template<typename Type>" before myClass definition, or it's not necessary?

Comment: @braga `template<typename Type>` declared a template parameter for the function `fn`. That function can be used with any class both with and without a template parameter itself (just like in the example). As shown in the example it works just fine with the class `A` which does not have any template parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support! I think that this is the answer i was looking for. Have a nice day!